# What is the difference in this CSS?

Tags: css

I usually just figure this out as I go and eventually it works but I am trying to work out what the difference really is so I can become a bit more adept with CSS, that in mind what is the difference between...

```
H2.class
```

and

```
H2 .class
```

and can I do....

```
.class.H2   ?
```

Comment: `h2.class` - refers to a `h2` tag with class as `class`. `h2 .class` - refers to any element with class as `class` under a `h2` tag. `.class.h2` would refer to an element with class as `class h2`

Comment: well the first should be any H2 with class class, while the second any descendant of an h2 element, with class class; this tells you all:http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: @Exitos don't forget to mark right answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2.class

```
<h2 class="class">stuff</div>
```

H2 .class

```
<h2><span class="class"></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `H2.class` will apply a style to this:

`<h2 class="class"></h2>`

The second `H2 .class` will apply a style to this:

`<h2><ANY class="class"></ANY></h2>`

And lastly the third `.class.H2` will apply a style to this:

`<ANY class="class H2"></ANY>`

Have a read up on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FSyntax

Answer (score 0):

1) H2.class means `<h2 class="class">..`

`<h2>` having class 'class'

2) H2 .class means `<h2><div class="class">..`

`<h2>` having descendent '.class'

3) .class.H2 means `<h2 class="class">..`

same as first

Answer (score 0):

```
H2.class
```

means the `h2` tag with `class="class"`

```
H2 .class
```

Means an element inside `h2` tag with `class="class"` such as:

```
<h2>THis is <span class"class">it</span></h2>
```

And so on..

```
.class.H2   ?
```

means the element with class of class with a class of `h2`.